# While Coding in C (MinGW) fatal error: sdkddkver.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c

I have just installed MinGW

This is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main() {
   printf("Hello, world!");
   return 0;
}
```

[image]

I am getting this error:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:73:0,
                 from c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:56,
                 from main.c:1: c:\mingw\include\w32api.h:59:23: fatal error: sdkddkver.h: No such file or directory  #include <sdkddkver.h>
                          ^ compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem with your mingw install, missing dependencies, or environment. Your C code is 100% correct so it's not really a "C" language question at all.

Typically... the only thing that REQUIRES mingw is compiling pre-existing Linux code for *distribution* on Windows.

If that's really what you need you could:

- Try installing Windows SDK to see if it resolves. The missing header: sdkdkver.h is part of Windows SDK (per a very quick google search).
- Uninstall mingw & re-install with different instructions.

  - I've had decent success with cygwin in the past.  Looks like MSYS2 is a viable alternative that's more dedicated to building windows "native" SW.
- Could dig through mingw documentation on environment variable setup.  Maybe missing something there.

Alternatives if you DON'T need to compile + distribute existing Linux source for Windows:

- Target Windows directly.  Free versions of Visual Studio support compiling C or C++ code.  So if you're writing FOR WINDOWS, this is your best bet.
- Could use Windows Subsystem For Linux ... if you're just looking run Linux SW or do Linux SW development on a natively windows machine.